# Two Kafka Server with Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-dataflow

Suppose there are two Kafka servers, one is for Spring Cloud Data flow and the other is for data source. I create a SpringBoot based application with Kafka dependency and use `@KafkaListener` as source and output the message. However, when I deploy the jar file to Spring Cloud Data Flow server and deploy the stream, the message was sent to Kafka that for data source but no the Kafka with Spring Cloud Data flow. The sample code gives like

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class TestSource {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic.datasource")
    public void source(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record) throws InterruptedException {

        logger.info("recv {} : {}", record.offset(), record.value());
        // some data pre processing
        source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
    }
```

My question is how we can get the data from one Kafka server and send the message to another Kafka server with Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Comment: When you say "two Kafka servers", do you mean two (single node) clusters?

Comment: Yes, one single node Kafka cluster for SCDF, the other for data source